# Discord.JS getting all attachments from a message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Hi I'm tying to make a say command that sends attachments that was sent while using the command for example someone uses !say while attaching 3 attachment and it sends the 3 attachments last time I tried to do it I could only get the first attachment but I want to get all the attachments that was attached with the message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the files or images that are attached to a message, you can access the `attachments` property of the `message` object. This will return a Collection of attachments that you can iterate through and attach to your new message.

e.g.

```js
client.on("message", message => {
    if (message.attachments) {
        let attachments = message.attachments;
        for (let file of attachments) {
            message.channel.send({files: [file]});
        }
    }
})
```

You can get more information about this in the Discord.js [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=attachments).

Comment: after putting this code I get an error when someone uses the command and attached attachments the error is `TypeError: Cannot read probably "path" of undefined`